# Keep deodorant container/bottle from always falling in cabinet?

Tags: organization

Deodorant containers are almost all designed with a base so thin, that no matter how precautious you are, when you reach to get something in your well organized bathroom cabinet, they always seem to fall like a bunch of dominoes. This "falling" behaviour is aggravated as time passes, since the deodorant is pushed up, making the top heavier than the bottom and thus less stable. They should be made to be stored upside down.

What are you doing for this ? Dump them all in a bigger container ?

Im talking about high and thin models like this one:

[image]

Comment: What sort of container are you talking about?  All those that I see have solid, stable bases.

Comment: added image of what im talking about.

Comment: Try turning it sideways so that something is to the left and right of it. Like a book in a bookshelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top-heavy narrow containers are not limited to deodorant, many face creams and make-up foundations work the same way.

A solution we used in the in the past was to store them in narrow basket-like shelves on the inside of the cabinet doors (similar to those in refrigerator doors); we had even one shelf that we'd added a narrow bungee-cord type of string above the original edge for especially tall containers. As the shelf was so narrow, the containers could only tip left or right and typically the shelves were so full that that didn't matter.

If your cabinets have a different interior layout, look into spice racks ([random example](http://www.amazon.de/Metaltex-364633095-Gew%C3%BCrzregal-3-Etagen-Polytherm/dp/B000T2AREI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1463734543&sr=8-1&keywords=Gew%C3%BCrzregal)), mounted inside or outside the cabinet. You might want to add a solid bottom instead of a wire one and then it can also house smaller containers from pill bottles to nail polish or those blood stopper sticks (depending on your cosmetic requirements). Great for coralling all those knick-knacks that tends to play domino on bathroom shelves.

Comment: Wife approves this answer

Answer (score 1):

I put all of my tall & narrow toiletries in a bin that fits them somewhat snugly. They don't have the room to fall over. Plus, I can pull out that bin and place it on the bathroom counter while I'm using something from it, and put it back in the cabinet (or drawer) when I'm done.

Alternately, you could place the deodorant in something with a wider base, like a glass.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate ***stable*** containers with the narrow ***tippy*** ones.

My tippy gel aftershave is between my shaving mug and my souvenir glass full of combs, and so on.

I'd better stop there to avoid embarrassing myself.
I know it sounds a bit O C; but, welcome to my orderly world

Answer (score 0):

My deodorant's the same shape as yours - I don't bother to put it in the cabinet any more (you're right, they do fall over easily, specially once you've used half of it), it drives me bonkers, and given I use it every day anyway, I stand it on top of the cabinet. Never falls over up there, but I'm guessing it might if you have sliding doors on your cabinet.

Comment: No top on the cabinet. Goes all the way to the ceiling.

Comment: Ah... you'll have to stand it in something then.

Answer (score 0):

Store them lying down instead of upright.

Comment: When you have multiple this gets disorganized really quick as they cannot be stored on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

Sane companies design their top-heavy bottles with a flat surface on top, so you can store the bottle upside down in a stable configuration. Buy those instead.